# Where can I store a very big data static resource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a WP(8) app which demands a big database (of words, to be precise). Actually, it has something like 300 000 values (currently stored in a text file). The thing is that I don't really want to open this file at every treatment, since it would add a lot of time to the process to parse the thing, that's why on the desktop version, I've got a module declaring a public array containing all the values.

But on Windows Phone, when I launch the app... it just crashes. The only reason I see is the array being to big, but where can I store all these strings then ? I don't think the List or the Dictionary will be better... Would you have any idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to create this array with only few items and than check if app crashes so You can be sure that size of array is Your Failing reason

Comment: Did it. Worked without any trouble.

Comment: why can't you extract the data and store it into a database and if you want the data to be presented in Windows Phone, then return the data in either JSON or XML.. have you done any research on the many alternatives to your current situation..? perhaps code wise you are doing something incorrectly.. can you show the code also can you tell us what the error is when the application is crashing..?

Comment: You can use SQLITE to create local database and store those data inside it.

Comment: well actually I thought of lots of things, but in my opinion, the idea to keep it hardcoded in an array loaded at application launch would make the process take less time.

Comment: I agree, Database (like SQLite) would benefit greatly in memory usage and wouldn't have to parse the file. Database wouldn't need to be parsed, nor loaded entirely in memory, you can query it for what you need (I find it hard to believe you need 300k words in memory when an SQL select could work).

Comment: Ok i'll look in this direction then. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As @MajkeloDev and @Ron Beyer said in comments:
Database (like SQLite) would benefit greatly in memory usage and wouldn't have to parse the file. Database wouldn't need to be parsed, nor loaded entirely in memory, you can query it for what you need (I find it hard to believe you need 300k words in memory when an SQL select could work).

Another way you can go if you don't want a database, is lazy loading your data, with a sort of pagination system, handling the disposal of unused items.
But that's too mess when you can just call the database.
It all depends on how do you need to use those words inside your application.